# Instantiate view/ do segue and pass data from button's title

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

If I click button I want to pass label in button to the next view. Next view need navigationItem title with label from buttons in previous view.
I've tried segues, but it didn't work. I am trying with instantiate view now, but it also doesn't work (next View appear but without title and needed data)

```
  **HomeTableViewController**
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "workoutFirstCell", for: indexPath) as! WorkoutTableCell
    
    cell.workoutField?.setTitle(workouts[indexPath.row].workoutTitle, for: .normal)
    cell.index = indexPath
    cell.cellDelegate = self
    
    
    
    
    return cell
}   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "workoutFirstCell", for: indexPath) as! WorkoutTableCell
    
    cell.workoutField?.setTitle(workouts[indexPath.row].workoutTitle, for: .normal)
    cell.index = indexPath
    cell.cellDelegate = self
    
    return cell
}
extension HomeTableViewController:WorkoutTableCellDelegate {
func onClickCell(index: Int) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "allWorkouts") as? AllWorkoutsViewController {
        vc.titleValue = workouts[index].workoutTitle
        vc.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}
```

}

Here is my cell controller

```
protocol WorkoutTableCellDelegate {
func onClickCell(index: Int)
```

}

```
class WorkoutTableCell: UITableViewCell {

var cellDelegate:WorkoutTableCellDelegate?
var index: IndexPath?
var item = AllWorkoutsViewController().navigationItem.title


@IBOutlet weak var workoutField: UIButton!

let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

let db = Firestore.firestore()

var models: [DataCell] = []

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
}


@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    cellDelegate?.onClickCell(index: (index?.row)!)
    
}
```

And View Controller where I want to display navigationItemTitle with label from button in previous view

```
class AllWorkoutsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var titleValue: String = ""
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

var db = Firestore.firestore()

var models: [DataCell] = []


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    navigationItem.title = titleValue
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code where you are pushing to a new view controller?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: nil)
    
    if segue.identifier == "youSegue" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let controller = segue.destination as! YourViewController
            controller.title = workouts[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still can't retrieve navigationItem title even when use your code

Comment: You can try self.title = self.titleValue in super.viewWillAppear. Used to work for me

Comment: Also doesn't work. It seems like a label from button can't send to next view

Comment: Maybe should I do some code in buttonTapped?